# Safest way in getting intvalue of an object

Tags: objective-c, int

Simple question [Objective-C]: (Couldn't find any solution till now).

I'm aware of `[id intValue];`. However this crashes my app because NSString can be `<Null>` sometimes, in my app. I can easily perform a check whether this is ` or not and then take decision accordingly. However I have many such situations (not recursive to use for or so) and was wondering what is the best possible way to make sure that my app doesn't crash.

Any Help is sincerely appreciated.

EDIT:

In my situation, I get a JSON Response from my server. and I create a NSDictionary from it. However, in my response I may get `<NSNull>` (Exactly like this, Due to a problem in the server API. Objective-C consider this (id) as NSNull class. What should I look for in this kind of situations?

Comment: In Objective-C, `[nil anyMethod]` should be `nil` or `0`. depending on the message signature.

Comment: If the `NSString` instance is `nil` it wouldn't crash (in ObjC you can send messages to `nil`). Worst case scenario, it would return `0`. So the problem is somewhere else...

Comment: Its not `nil`. Its `<NSNull>`. Please check my edit once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is two most common ways:

First method:

Check, wether string can actually respond to `intValue`. Or check if it's `NSString` or `NSNumber`.

```
NSString *string = ...;
int intValue = ([string respondsToSelector:@selector(intValue)]) ? [string intValue] : 0;
```

For convenience you can write a macros for this

```
#define intValueFromAnyObject(obj) ([obj respondsToSelector:@selector(intValue)]) ? [obj intValue] : 0;
int intValue = intValueFromAnyObject(string);
```

Second way (I like it much more):

Write a category on NSNull so it won't crash when you send it an unrecognized selector (intValue for example)

```
@interface NSNull (myExtension)
- (int)intValue;
@end

@implementation NSNull (myExtension)
- (int)intValue
{
    return 0;
}
@end
```

From now on any time you'll try to get intValue from an NSNull object, you will get 0.

Comment: @hybridcattt Is there any particular name for this technique i.e. Defining Class in different files (Am I correct in saying this?)?

Comment: @iRaviiVooda It's called Categories in objective-C

Comment: @iRaviiVooda yes, you can create new file -> objective-c category (this will give you a ready template), and import it in .pch file in the project.
In our case names of the files will be NSNull+myExtension.h and NSNull+myExtension.m

Comment: you saved my life !

Answer (score 3):

```
int value = (string) ? [string intValue] : 0;
```

0 or other return value when string is nil

Comment: This only checks if string is not nil, which is absolutely irrelevant to the question

Comment: can you reformulate your question?